# Linkedin authentication error via api

Tags: linkedin-api

We tried to authenticate via linkedin api , it throws error as

"Invalid http request". Please check the attachement.

FYI: Its already worked properly , but now we don't why not working suddenly.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3rxZ.png)

Comment: Can you apply these steps. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Comment: Hi its already worked properly for all the account from last 2 years. WE are facing this issue from last 42 hrs only. Everthing in authentication url is fine.